# Quotient group isomorphic to $\mathbb Q^∗$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

It is given that $G=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b\\ 
  0 & c
\end{pmatrix}\text{ with }a,c \in \mathbb Q^∗\text{ and }b \in \mathbb Q\right\}$ is a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb Q)$, the group of invertible 2×2-matrices with rational coefficients.

$N=\left \{\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b\\ 
  0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\text{ with }a \in \mathbb Q^∗\text{ and }b \in \mathbb Q\right\}$.

Show that N is a normal subgroup of G and that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q^∗$, which is a group under multiplication.

My attempt: N is a normal subgroup of G if $gNg^{-1} = N$

$\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b\\ 
  0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b\\ 
  0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b\\ 
  0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}
  a & ab+b\\ 
  0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}
  1/a & -b/a\\ 
  0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ =$\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & ab\\ 
  0 & 1.
\end{pmatrix}$ = N if $a = 1$.

Then to prove that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q^∗$ , define the map $\varphi$: $G/N \rightarrow \mathbb Q^∗ $  by $\varphi\left(\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b\\ 
  0 & c.
\end{pmatrix}\right)= a$.

I know that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q^∗$ iff the map is surjective and homomorphic.
It is homomorphic since
$$\begin{align*}\varphi\left(\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b\\ 
  0 & c.
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
  d & e\\ 
  0 & f.
\end{pmatrix}\right) &= \varphi\left(\begin{pmatrix}
  ad & ae+bf\\ 
  0 & cf.
\end{pmatrix}\right)\\
 &=ad\\
&=\varphi\left(\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b\\ 
  0 & c.
\end{pmatrix}\right) \varphi\left(\begin{pmatrix}
  d & e\\ 
  0 & f.
\end{pmatrix}\right).\end{align*}$$

But I don't know how to prove that it is surjective. Could please someone explains to me how to do it?

Comment: You're 99% of the way there. To prove it's surjective, you just have to write down, given $a \in \mathbb{Q}^\times$ arbitrary, an example of a matrix mapping to $a$.

Comment: You are 1% of the way there. You have not conjugated by a general element of $G$ but by one which also lies in $N$ - in fact you've written down $xxx^{-1}$.

Comment: Hint: look at the map $\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b\\ 
  0 & c
\end{pmatrix}\mapsto c$.  Check that it is a homomorphism, has kernel $N$ and is onto the non-zero rationals.

Comment: As a general piece of advice: exercises of the type "show that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $G'$" always want you to find a surjective homomorphism $G\to G'$ with kernel $N$. Then everything follows directly from the fundamental theorem on homomorphisms.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get how to show that the map is surjective. Could someone give maybe an example, please